# How to identify the lat/long location from where the IoT button click was made

Tags: iot, aws-iot

How to identify the lat/long location from where the IoT button click was made

https://aws.amazon.com/iotbutton/

Answer (score 2):

There are lookups you can do from IP Address to location. i.e http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201

Unfortunately for you, IoT Button clicks only give 3 event parameters:

```
 clickType: event.clickType, // (string) the type of press; can be "SINGLE", "DOUBLE" or "LONG"
 serialNumber: event.serialNumber, // (string) device's serial number, from the back of the button.
 batteryVoltage: event.batteryVoltage // (string) device's voltage level in millivolts. e.g. "1567mV"
```

If your set up of an IoT button involves putting it on a wifi network, and having it be stationary, that is the time to manually map the serial number to a latitude/longitude. Then do a look-up from serial number to lat/long.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-lambda-rule.html

[2] https://www.losant.com/blog/getting-started-with-aws-iot-button-losant