# AWS IoT Button "JSON.stringify"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, geojson

Dear all AWS IoT developers
I realized that I can only get three parameters as illustrated from the code below:

```
// Amazon's IoT button sends three parameters when it is pressed ...
var body = JSON.stringify({
    clickType: event.clickType, // (string) the type of press; can be "SINGLE", "DOUBLE" or "LONG"
    serialNumber: event.serialNumber, // (string) device's serial number, from the back of the button.
    batteryVoltage: event.batteryVoltage // (string) device's voltage level in millivolts. e.g. "1567mV"
});
```

My question is: is there any way to get other parameters utilizing from 
**JSON.stringify**.

PS: here is the complete code by this [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/LosantGists/af84e11c3622fb0b967e1fafacfeb56f/raw/f6ab1187d282b5321cffc07eda0d989d034e92d1/aws-iot-button-to-losant-lambda-function.js).

Comment: Hard to follow the question, but maybe try `JSON.stringify(event)`

Comment: As I tried to put other variable, e.g. "**event**", I got as an output "**[object Object]**", which eventually brings null meaning for end users ;(

Comment: If I understood Mr. Catalyst correctly, I tried also `JSON.stringify(event);`, and I got only the three parameters mentioned above.

Comment: in this case that means event only contains those three things. You have to access any other data using something besides `event`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html - not everything you need is specifically on that screen, you'll have to read around. Unless what you want is in the `context` which is not likely feature-related data, then you have to look into passing more data to your handler from whatever upstream is calling it.

Comment: The button is a device that notifies you when it is pressed.  What information are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post by Stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915934/how-to-identify-the-lat-long-location-from-where-the-iot-button-click-was-made/49183709#49183709), json can only specify these parameters. Other parameters such as ""lat/log"" would be hard define.
A suggested solution for finding lat/long would probably by writing nodeJS code utilizing from npm `googlemaps`.